# redirecting user varying location path

Tags: php

If I have a file located at `"Project/index.php"` which is where I want my user to get redirected no matter where they are in the file structure.

I have two files with different file paths:

```
"Project/file1.php"

"Project/sub/file2.php"
```

On both files the user can click on logout which takes them to the logout page.
The logout page is located here: `"Project/sub/logout.php"` 
which contains the code:

```
header('Location: ../index.php');
die();
```

If the user was on file2 then this script would work however if the user was on file1 then the script wouldnt work.

Is there a way to allow the user to logout no matter where they are in a file structure without having to create multiple logout pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a path relative to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of the project.

```
header('Location: /Project/index.php');
exit;
```

Alternately, if your server is setup right to auto-serve `index.php`, then do this:

```
header('Location: /');
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use absolute URLs for that:

```
header('Location: http://my.site/logout');
```

or you can use a URL relative to your site:

```
header('Location: /logout');
```

Both code samples will redirect to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

why not use an absolute path?

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/yourpath/yourfile.php";
header("Location:" . $path);
```